# How to search a row in current page in dojo EnhancedGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I need build a search functionality for a grid which binds with QueryReadStore. I tried using Search plugin but I think that work if you the grid is bind with ItemFileReadStore . Can someone help how to achieve search on QueryReadyStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var grid_obj = dijit.byId(your_grid_id);
    var grid_row_count = grid_obj.rowCount;
    for(i =0 i<grid_row_count;i++)
    {
       var item = grid_obj.getItem(i); 
    // Then compare for the value
    }

//Note:this is full grid scan,dont use if there is large data.
```